# Importing a shapefile with no specifed projection to Postgres?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql, coordinate-system

I am working with [a shapefile](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1996/of96-092/arcview_files/) that does not come with a `.prj` file - only `.shp`, `.shx` and `.dbf` files. The file's [accompanying README](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1996/of96-092/arcview_files/arcview.readme) says:

```
ALL DATA IS IN A GEOGRAPHIC COORDINATE SYSTEM (NOT PROJECTED)
USING DECIMAL DEGREES
```

I want to use `shp2pgsql` to import the data into Postgres, but I know I should use `-s` to specify the source SRID.

But what SRID should I be using in this case?

I tried importing it into Postgres without a source SRID, but looking at it in QGIS it seemed to have imported badly.

UPDATE: I tried `shp2pgsql -s 4326:5070` and that seems to work OK. I think "geographic coordinate system" might actually mean `EPSG:4326` - is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A geographic coordinate system refers to degrees of latitude and longitude, of which the standard SRID would be WGS84 with EPSG code of 4326. There are some variations on that though but you're likely safe as that is the most common and default projection.

So yes, you are correct and in your shp2pgsql call you are transforming it to a projected SRID using the -s flag.